# Modifying the resultant Executing assembly path c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting my executing assembly path in string and I don't want the entire path I need to use a portion of it and need to access it another folder from that path.

Let's say I need to get an xml from the folder

`" E:\Mahi_WorkSpace\TFS \Atrias.WebAutomationTesting\XmlFolder"`

where my Executing assembly path is

```
" E:\Mahi_WorkSpace\TFS \Atrias.WebAutomationTesting\TestResults\t.mahidharreddy_123 2016-10-24 07_39_26\Out"
```

Now I need to only `"E:\Mahi_WorkSpace\TFS \Atrias.WebAutomationTesting\ "` from the executing assembly string

```
 public string GetStringBody()
    {
         System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new    CompilerParameters();
         string path=Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
//srting xmlpath=??
         return xmlpath;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just another possible solution:

```
public string GetStringBody() {
    System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    return di.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName; // here you should define how many level you want to up
}
```

Comment: @JAYDHEER Glad to have been of help

Comment: Hi Mega Tron that worked fine thanks for the quick rsponse

Comment: Hi Mega Tron that worked fine thanks for the quick rsponse –

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

`string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(TestContext.TestRunDirectory));`

This will give you the parent directory of the `TestResults` folder created by the `Atrias.WebAutomationTesting` which, I believe, is what you are looking for.

Reference: [MSDN: TestContext.TestRunDirectory Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.testrundirectory.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link Shiva

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the parent directories until get to the target node.

```
var currentDirectoryPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

var parentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(currentDirectoryPath);
while (!string.Equals(parentDirectory.Name, "Atrias.WebAutomationTesting", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    parentDirectory = parentDirectory.Parent;
    if (parentDirectory == null)
        break;
}

if (parentDirectory != null)
{
    var targetDirectory = parentDirectory.FullName + "\\Test";
    MessageBox.Show(targetDirectory);
}
```